# response to vulgarism and it's origin and definition

Tags: scripture, vedas, shloka

Bad, good, vulgar, non vulgar *might* actually come down to perception but when it comes down to society and culture(*sanskriti/sanskar*), social norms, boundaries and values, then there is definitely a solid line that defines **vulgarity.**  In this question I mostly address the vocal form of this vulgarity, i.e. using non-social, rough/vulgar words.

I strictly follow rules to avoid such arrogance but in this mass population and your day to day life, it's hard to come across people who don't make use of such words/statements. I really get confused when someone pronounces such thing. Should I slap the person infront of me or just ignore it? Request him not to speak them?

So, I turn to vedic texts/scriptures to find a mantra, a story, a sloka? Is there a story depicting such an instance of event? Or a sloka, a remedy of ancient source to deal with the situation?

EDIT: **If this all seems a bit confusing, I think all I am trying to find out is how do the vedas/scriptures define vulgarism in terms of speech, act, vision and various other forms of perception and convey.**

Comment: What compels you to view this interpersonal situation through a religious lens and pursue scriptural precedents and remedies? IMO you'd be better served seeking advice for this situation on the [Interpersonal SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @iruvar , vedas do guide the way to live your life, and also teach you about how to tame your emotions be it kaama or krodha ,harsha and ullasa. various scriptures be it tantric or vedantic also define aspects relating to birth and living that at some point might be considered as vulgar. So, I wondered about the social aspect of those.

Comment: @iruvar , or atleast tell me how do the vedas define what vulgarism is?

Comment: @iruvar, I edited my question

Comment: Not everything is found in the Vedas. The type of answer you are looking for is usually found in Itihasas and Puranas. So I'd replace 'Vedas' with 'scripture' everywhere.

Comment: @sv, yeah, I try to come up with the correct term. I mean the scriptures written by rishis and such profound people, anything like puranas, upanishads, vedas etc

Comment: When you are not sure where a particular story is found you should not mention Vedas, Upanishads and such. Ask an open-ended question so answers can draw from various sources. I'd suggest removing 'Vedas' from the tags and the body.

Comment: @sv. , but, I don't want just any writer writing in sanskrit, just the rishis, or people as such, which has ideal knowledge/absolute knowledge free from impurity

Comment: 'any writer writing in sanskrit' - that's automatically off-topic for this site...however, rishis are also men, they did not fall from the sky. I would take advice from anyone as long as it's sensible.

Comment: @sv. , I did mention rishis have purda gyan. Or atleast they're from a profound source, e.g. from guru shishya parampara, or from paramatma himself

Answer (score 1):

One man's meat is other man's poison. What is vulgar to you may sound like a lullaby to other. How to avoid such a situation? Yes you can slap the person and in return get few. Is this the solution? NO.

Your mind is in turmoil and you want to calm down. Recite 
Gayatri Mantra or 
OM NAMA SHIVAY or
ACHYUTANANDA GOVINDA.
as many times till your blood pressure returns to normal and the mind gets cooled.

I follow this and find solace.

Comment: what do you think the vedas and scriptures define vulgarity as?